# Regex to sanitize sentences, almost done

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

My current php sentence sanitizer function:

```
function sanitize_sentence($string) {
    $pats = array(
    '/([.!?]\s{2}),/',      # Abc.  ,Def
    '/\.+(,)/',             # ......,
    '/(!)!+/',              # abc!!!!!!!!
    '/\s+(,)/',             # abc   , def
    '/([a-zA-Z])\1\1/');    # greeeeeeen
    $fixed = preg_replace($pats,'$1',$string);
    $fixed = preg_replace('/,(?!\s)/',', ',$fixed);
    return $fixed;
}

echo sanitize_sentence('hello!!!!!!there should be a space after the exclamation mark.right???????yes.right,');
```

The result should be:

> hello! there should be a space after the exclamation mark. right? yes. right.

So, what's still missing is:

1. an extra space should be inserted after any !?,.if there is more text at the right.
2. if the last character is a comma (or any other character different than a-zA-Z0-9!?.), it should be replaced with a dot.
3. if the user writes more than one question mark, it should be converted to one (?????? = ?). That is working fine for me for exclamation marks, but somehow it's not working for the others.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements:

1. An extra space should be inserted after any `!?,.` if there is more text at the right.

   We can use another regex to do this replacement:

   ```
   $fixed = preg_replace( '/([!?,.])(\S)/', '$1 $2', $fixed); # spaces after punctuation, if it doesn't exist already
   ```
2. If the last character is a comma (or any other character different than `a-zA-Z0-9!?.`), it should be replaced with a dot.

   You can get this with a regex, anchored at the end of the text:

   ```
   $fixed = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9!?.]+$/', '.', $fixed); # end of string must end in period
   ```
3. If the user writes more than one question mark, it should be converted to one (?????? = ?). That is working fine for me for exclamation marks, but somehow it's not working for the others.

   It's not working because `?` is a special character in regexes, you need to escape it. Replace the appropriate entry with this:

   ```
   '/(!|\?)\1+/',              # abc!!!!!!!!, abc?????????
   ```

And now, [the output is](http://3v4l.org/aGsIc#v430):

```
hello! there should be a space after the exclamation mark. right? yes. right.
```

Comment: Just noticed one last detail that should be covered; if the user types: hello!. (or hello!..) it should be converted to (hello!) -- it also applies to hello?. etc -- This is intended for periods only.

Comment: sorry, just noticed it won't work with `hello friend.....?` those periods are being separated into `.. .. .` for some reason.

Comment: @andufo - These new requirements are suited for another question - My answer fulfills the requirements in your original post.

Comment: sorry, my bad. your solution has been checked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `$pats` for the question mark replacing. I haven't finished the rest.

```
'/(\?)\?+/',              # abc?????????
```